# ntpd installed to local directory, now have two versions

Tags: debian, upgrade, ntp, ntpd

I got the latest version of ntpd because the binary releases have vulnerabilities. Unfortunately, after I built it and ran `make install`, it was installed to /usr/local/sbin, but the system is running the old version of ntpd which is located in /usr/sbin. I have three questions:

(1) How can I fix this, so I am running the version that I built?

(2) Why does `make install` put it in a different directory than its normal location in the Debian distribution (I am running Wheezy)?

(3) It seems like a bad idea to have two different versions on my computer. Should I delete the original version or replace it with the new version somehow?

Comment: There are no vulnerabilities in the ntp binaries shipped with Debian.

Comment: @dfc Actually, if you go to ntp.org they have a security notice right on their front page recommending installation of the development build. The stable build (which is installed and runs by default in Debian Wheezy) is vulnerable to a DDOS reflection attack.

Comment: If you "actually" read the security notice you will see that the vulnerability is the result of configuration defaults. You can "patch this vulnerability" by adding `restrict default......noquery` or `disable monitor` in you ntp.conf

Comment: You could do a backport, but debian patches security problems in stable, so this should not normally be necessary for that reason. Having looked at the ntp page, I agree with def that upgrading is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Well, I suppose you can disable the monlist, but then you are removing functionality from the service.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The NTP organization specifically recommends as mitigation "Upgrade to 4.2.7p26 or later". Installing Debian out of the box results in having the vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the easy copy the binaries in place as mentioned in the other answer or you can use uupdate to build a new debian package from the latest source. It is basically as easy as:

```
# apt-get build-dep ntp
# apt-get source ntp
# wget http://ntp.org/blah-src/ntp-version.tar.gz
# cd ntp-4.2.6.p5+dfsg
# uupdate ../ntp-version.tar.gz 
# cd ../ntp-version
# dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -nc 
# dpkg -i ../ntp*.deb
```

Comment: Thats interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Any program built using autotools (i.e. ones using  `configure; make; make install` to build and install) will normally default to installing under `/usr/local`

You can change the base directory by typing something like `./configure --prefix=/usr`.  When you install it with `make install` the binaries will then be written out to directories  under `/usr`

Comment: Ok, but can I can I just install right over the old ntpd? Won't that leave a lot of junk from the old version in the folder?

Comment: Unlikely.  Chances this version will be just an incremental update.  I doubt it would cause any issues like that.